# Qual a diferença de se definir uma dependência como group ou module no gradle catalog?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle

Estou estudando e usando o catálogo de versões do gradle para gerenciar as minhas dependências e ví que posso defini-lá no arquivo libs.versions.toml na parte de librares de duas formas, posso definir como group ou como module; andei olhando na documentação do gradle e em outros posts mas ainda não ficou claro qual a diferença de se usar um ou de se usar outro. Por exemplo, abaixo defini duas dependências como module e as demais como group.

```
[libraries]
androidx-ktx = { group = "androidx.core", name = "core-ktx", version.ref = "ktx"}
androidx = {module = "androidx.appcompat:appcompat", version.ref = "appcompat"}
material-design = {group = "com.google.android.material", name = "material", version.ref = "design"}
constraint-layout = {group = "androidx.constraintlayout", name = "constraintlayout", version.ref = "constraint"}
junit-test = {module = "junit:junit", version.ref = "junit"}
```

Alguém sabe qual a diferença entre elas e qual ganho de se utilizar um ou outro?